Can you please prove that the criteria for 1st order homogeneous differential equation also holds for the 1st order linear homogeneous differential eq
I have come across the two criteria for the differential equations to be homogeneous. They are:

The 1st-order differential equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ will be homogeneous if $f(tx,ty)=f(x,y)$ for all real values of $t$.
The 1st-order linear differential equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$ will be homogeneous if $Q(x)=0$. So, $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=0$ is homogeneous.

I found that, 1st-order linear differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=0$ is also a 1st-order differential equation, since $\frac{dy}{dx}=-P(x)y\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$
$\\$ where $f(x,y)=-P(x)y$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.
Now, $f(tx,ty)=-P(tx)ty\ne -P(x)y $ for all real values of $t$. So, the condition $f(tx,ty)=f(x,y)$ is not satisfied here. So, it cannot be homogeneous by the condition for 1st order homogeneous differential equation.
I am very puzzled by this contradiction. I would appreciate any kind of help in solving this doubt. Thank you.

The word homogeneous is applied to different things in the two definitions. In the first case, we’re speaking of homogeneity of the function $f$, but in the second case, we’re speaking of homogeneity of the operator $y\mapsto y’+Py$. So it’s not a contradiction but an implicitness in the language where one doesn’t specify the thing whose homogeneity is being referred to.

Thank you @peek-a-boo .
